# Why is a "pending suggested edit" warning not formatted as a pop up, but as a single line?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, markdown, error-message

I am using Google chrome web browser, I found one question need some edits. Then I clicked on the edit question link on the question and got this page,

[image]

I know this error is ok, But the way this is displayed on new page only one line is wrong. Please let me know how this come and need to fix same.

Comment: How is it wrong? It looks correct to me.

Comment: No, some day's back it use to give one alert with same message

Comment: are you requesting that the page be formatted better?

Comment: Yes, it should like most popup's in site